# Limit a firefox extension to a specific domain

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I would like to write a firefox extension. This extension is not a generic extension but work specifically for a domain where I need to highlight specific html components.

How should I do that? I just want the js loaded when the user is browsing a specific domain.

My current `overaly.js` is basically empty (generated by the Extension Wizard):

```
var myextension = {
  onLoad: function() {
    // initialization code
    this.initialized = true;
    this.strings = document.getElementById("myextension-strings");
  },

  onMenuItemCommand: function(e) {
    var promptService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/prompt-service;1"]
                                  .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPromptService);
    promptService.alert(window, this.strings.getString("helloMessageTitle"),
                                this.strings.getString("helloMessage"));
  },

  onToolbarButtonCommand: function(e) {
    // just reuse the function above.  you can change this, obviously!
    myextension.onMenuItemCommand(e);
  }
};

window.addEventListener("load", myextension.onLoad, false);
```

And my `ff-overlay.xul` is:

```
myextension.onFirefoxLoad = function(event) {
  document.getElementById("contentAreaContextMenu")
          .addEventListener("popupshowing", function (e){ myextension.showFirefoxContextMenu(e); }, false);
};

myextension.showFirefoxContextMenu = function(event) {
  // show or hide the menuitem based on what the context menu is on
  document.getElementById("context-myextension").hidden = gContextMenu.onImage;
};

window.addEventListener("load", myextension.onFirefoxLoad, false);
```

I was thinking to go *neanderthal* and do a check inside `myextension.onFirefoxLoad` to see if the currentpage is the one I want but that requires the user to click the proper item on the context menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not totally following what you have because both of those look like JS files, not XUL files. But what you probably want to do is [listen for the `load` event coming from the web pages that are loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/On_page_load). Then, in your event loader, just look at each page that loads and see whether it's coming from the specific domain you want.

A great (though not always quite as easy as it sounds) way to find out how to do something in a Firefox addon is to find another addon that does something similar. [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6622/) and [Inspect Context](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3276/) are your friends! The first such addon that comes to mind in this case is [WikiTrust](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/11087/) so you could try looking at that one to see if it gives you any inspiration.

Comment: It was `onPageLoad` I was looking for. I have a second question related to this. Since I don't need to edit the browser UI, do I still need `overlay.xul`? At this point should it be a default `overlay.xul` with only a `script` tag to call the extension js file?

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. Just include your script tag, and maybe a stringbundle to externalize your strings. Then if you later decide to add something else, you can always do so.